# How to filter an array by two indvidual strings from an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I need to filter 13 items by two different select box values, and I'm getting stuck on persisting the filter.

I have two select boxes that I've selected like so:

```
let pickupLocation = document.querySelector("#pa_location");  //values are 'complete-set', 'neck', 'bridge'.

let pickupType = document.querySelector("#pa_type1"); // Values are 'soapbar', 'dogear', 'short'.
```

### What's Working:

I'm initializing an object like so:

```
const activeFilters = {};
```

To populate the values like so:

```
//Persist the Complete Set / Single
pickupLocation.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (pickupLocation.value === "complete-set") {
    activeFilters.location = "set";
  } else {
    activeFilters.location = "single";
  }
});

pickupType.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (pickupType.value === "soapbar") {
    activeFilters.type = "soapbar";
  } else if (pickupType.value === "dogear") {
    activeFilters.type = "dogear";
  } else {
    activeFilters.type = "short";
  }
});

// Returns something like
// {location: single, type: dogear}
```

I'm trying to filter an array of input elements by their value. I have 13 inputs each with a value containing words like `set`, `single`, `dogear`, `soapbar` etc.

### Where I'm stuck:

I have a filter function that I'm trying to filter the values of these inputs by two values of the `activeFilters` object:

```
const performFilter = (covers) => {
  let results;
  let filteredValues = Object.values(activeFilters);

  filteredValues.forEach((value) => {
    results = covers.filter((cover) => cover.value.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });

  return results;
};
```

The problem is my function is returning only one of the two words. For instance, if the my `activeFilters` object is `{location: set, type: dogear}` the filtered `results` array contains only one of them. Where am I going wrong?

## Edit:

This function returns all inputs that match one of the `activeFilters`, and I apologize if I wasn't clear above, but I'd like it to match ALL of the Active Filters. Is this possible with the function below?

```
const performFilter = (covers) => {
  let results = []; // initialise the array
  let filteredValues = Object.values(activeFilters);

  filteredValues.forEach((value) => {
    let res = covers.filter((cover) => cover.value.indexOf(value) !== -1);
    results.push(...res);
  });

  console.log(results);
};
```

## CODEPEN:

[Codepen!](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/MWoeoGP?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const performFilter = (covers) => {
  let results = []; // initialise the array
  let filteredValues = Object.values(activeFilters);

  filteredValues.forEach((value) => {
    let res = covers.filter((cover) => cover.value.indexOf(value) !== -1);
    // push the value it find individually
     // you were overriding the previous value with result = filter()

    results.push(...res); 


  });

  return results;
};
```

// according to Edited question

```
const performFilter = (covers) => {
  let results = []; // initialise the array
  let filteredValues = Object.values(activeFilters);

   return covers.filter((cover) => filteredValues.every(value => cover.value.indexOf(value) !== -1));

};
```

Comment: Does `.find` only show one result at a time? This function is only returning two results max, when it should be returning around 5-7.

Comment: sorry, might have misunderstood the question, updated can you check it this answer your question

Comment: So this is the right track, but I'm wondering how to return only the items that have BOTH tags?. For instance, I have inputs with values like polished-nickel-soapbar-single and polished-nickel-dogear-set. I'm wondering how to check for both of the elements in the filter array. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer, now you want a list of covers that have both the filtered values

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working as intended. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood clearly your question, so feel free to comment it.

First, I suggest you to filter your `covers` array and inside the filtering function iterate through your selected filters. This is because the filter function returns the array already filtered and so you don't need to assign it to a result variable or things like that. So based on that, try this:

```
const performFilter = (covers) => {
    let results;
    let filteredValues = Object.values(activeFilters);
    
    const filteredCovers = covers.filter((cover)  => {
        return cover.value.split("-").some((tag) => filteredValues.includes(tag))
    });
    
    console.log(filteredCovers)
};
```

Comment: So this is the right track, but I'm wondering how to return only the items that have BOTH `tag`s?. For instance, I have inputs with values like `polished-nickel-soapbar-single` and `polished-nickel-dogear-set`. I'm wondering how to check for both of the elements in the filter array. Thank you!